# Why is the default of Pandas get_dummies()'s parameter drop_first = False?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, dummy-variable

Pandas' function `pandas.get_dummies()` returns for a categorical variable with *k* levels either

- *k* dummy variables (= one-hot encoding) if `drop_first = False`
- *k* - 1 dummy variables (= dummy encoding) if `drop_first = True`

Both contain the same information since when an observation is not any of the *k*-1 levels, it is the remaining level.

I've read that sklearn's Regression and other models need to be fit with dummy encoding, i.e. *k*-1 dummy variables, if you use their default parameters. However, the default of setting in `pandas.get_dummies()` is `drop_first = False`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I'm sure it's just for legacy compatibility.  The change was made [here](https://github.com/cldy/pandas/commit/77b3a4e93819b04e47c82b562dc9569ccf00d392), and officially added in `0.18.0`.  If they had made it default to `True`, plenty of existing code would behave very differently.  It was added with the rational: ["Sometimes it will be useful to..."](https://github.com/cldy/pandas/commit/77b3a4e93819b04e47c82b562dc9569ccf00d392#diff-0bcfd9cf16bd403bd2d64dba40cafb32R544), not "it should by default behave like this..."